# How to compare sqlite columns?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a table in my imported prepopulated sqlite db, and rows A1, B1, A2, B2, A3, B3. I randomly set their content to some buttons. Now I want when a user click pair of buttons, for example button2 and after that button5, to compare if content of those buttons match, ie I want A1 and B1 to be pairs, also A2 and B2 and so on. So I want to compare if their columns match. How to do that? Here's my code so far:

```
public class Game extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

LinkedList<Long> mAnsweredQuestions = new LinkedList<Long>();

private String generateWhereClause(){
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (Long l : mAnsweredQuestions){
            result.append(" AND _ID <> " + l);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    final OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
        };

    Button a1,a2,a3,a4,b1,b2,b3,b4;

        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spojnice);

            a1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA1);
        a2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA2);
        a3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA3);
        a4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA4);
            b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB2);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB3);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB4);

nextQuestion();
        }

private void nextQuestion() {

        TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();

        try{ 

            mDbHelper.open();

            Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestData(generateWhereClause());

            mAnsweredQuestions.add(c.getLong(0));

            List<String> labelsA = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> labelsB = new ArrayList<String>();

            labelsA.add(c.getString(2));
            labelsA.add(c.getString(4));
            labelsA.add(c.getString(6));
            labelsA.add(c.getString(8));

            labelsB.add(c.getString(3));
            labelsB.add(c.getString(5));
            labelsB.add(c.getString(7));
            labelsB.add(c.getString(9));

            Collections.shuffle(labelsA);
            Collections.shuffle(labelsB);

            a1.setText(labelsA.get(0));
            a1.setTag(labelsA.get(0));
            a1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            a2.setText(labelsA.get(1));
            a2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            a3.setText(labelsA.get(2));
            a3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            b1.setText(labelsB.get(0));
            b1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            b2.setText(labelsB.get(1));
            b2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

            b3.setText(labelsB.get(2));
            b3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

    }
        finally{ 
            mDbHelper.close();
        }


}
```

Here' my db helper:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat window
//destination path (location) of our database on device
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/rs.androidaplikacije.spojnice/databases/"; 
private static String DB_NAME ="pitanja.sqlite";// Database name
private static SQLiteDatabase mDataBase; 
private final Context mContext;
private static final String KEY_ID = "_ID";
private static final String KEY_PITANJE = "PITANJE";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "tblPitanja";

public DataBaseHelper(Context mojContext) 
{
    super(mojContext, DB_NAME, null, 1);// 1? its Database Version
    DB_PATH = mojContext.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
    this.mContext = mojContext;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException
{
    //If database not exists copy it from the assets


        this.getReadableDatabase();
        this.close();
        try 
        {
            //Copy the database from assests
            copyDataBase();
            Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
        } 
        catch (IOException mIOException) 
        {
            throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
        }
    }
    /*Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/Da Name
    private boolean checkDataBase()
    {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
        return dbFile.exists();
    }
    */

    //Copy the database from assets
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
    {
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0)
        {
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }

    //Open the database, so we can query it
    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException
    {
        String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        //Log.v("mPath", mPath);
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        //mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
        return mDataBase != null;
    }
    @Override
    public void close() 
    {
        if(mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
        }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        Log.w("DataBaseHelper", "Upgrading database!!!!!");
          onCreate(arg0);

    }

}
```

and my test adapter:

```
public class TestAdapter 
{
    protected static final String TAG = "DataAdapter";

    private final Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private DataBaseHelper mDbHelper;

    public TestAdapter(Context context) 
    {
        this.mContext = context;
        mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(mContext);
    }

    public TestAdapter createDatabase() throws SQLException 
    {
        try 
        {
            mDbHelper.createDataBase();
        } 
        catch (IOException mIOException) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, mIOException.toString() + "  UnableToCreateDatabase");
            throw new Error("UnableToCreateDatabase");
        }
        return this;
    }

    public TestAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        try 
        {
            mDbHelper.openDataBase();
            mDbHelper.close();
            mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        } 
        catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "open >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
            throw mSQLException;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void close() 
    {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

     public Cursor getTestData(String whereClause)
     {;
         try
         {
             String sql ="SELECT * FROM tblPitanja WHERE 1 = 1 " + whereClause + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";

             Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
             if (mCur!=null)
             {
                mCur.moveToNext();
             }
             return mCur;
         }
         catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
         {
             Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
             throw mSQLException;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: is A1, B1, A2, B2, A3, B3 columns or rows? Can you specify an example of table how it would look like with some dummy data?

Comment: Columns. I have a question in 1st row 'question' "connect names of actors" and in A1 is for example Sylvester and i B1 is Stallone, in A2 is Keanu, in B2 is Reaves and so on. 2nd row can be tennis players, 3rd row can be "connect colors with fruit". Now i shuffle one random row and set the A's in left set of buttons and B's to right side buttons. And a user should connect them.

Comment: when you say first row has a question "Connect names of actors" so will it be replicated in all the columns A1, B1, A2,B2,A3,B3 and then in the second row you will have all the values of actor names...similarly next row will have a question replicated in all the columns and then the next row will have all the values?

Comment: It's something like this [link](http://i.imgur.com/YvHD2f9.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need retrieves values from database again after they're already on buttons.

A good approach is setting tag for each button as you started ahead. Set the same tag for buttons that match and when clicked verify if the tags match.

Following your structure, you can retrieve values for labels from database, and for `labelsA` and `labelsB`, they're could be a Collection of

```
class MyStruct {
    private String label;
    private String tag;
}
```

Thus, initialize then like

```
ArrayList<MyStruct> labelsA = new ArrayList<MyStruct>();
ArrayList<MyStruct> labelsB = new ArrayList<MyStruct>();
```

To add each value, do

```
// labelForButton1 and tagForButton1And
labelsA.add(new MyStruct("labelForButton1", "tagForButton1And2"); // this tag should be the same to button that matches
labelsB.add(new MyStruct("labelForButton2", "tagForButton1And2"); 

Collections.shuffle(labelsA);
Collections.shuffle(labelsB);

a1.setText(labelsA.get(0).getLabel());
a1.setTag(labelsA.get(0).getTag());

// and so on to a2, b2 etc
```

In listeners, you can verify if tag for each button matches.

Comment: I get errors on getLabel() and getTag(). "Create method 'getLabel() in type 'MyStruct'". Also I didn't quite get this "tagForButton1And2" part. Why tags for two buttons in one string? If you could be more extensive I would appreciate, this is all very new for me. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I made some progress, please check out my answer below.

Comment: Where, pal? I'm still want help you.

Answer (score 0):

So lets say that user picks on Sylvester first... then Stallone, do you want to make sure if that is in the database?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f28af/1

So, what you could do is, when user clicks the first button, get its value and store it in a variable var1 = 'Sylvester'. On the second click, store that value in var2 = 'Stallone'. Now all you have to do is, execute the following line and see if the count is > 0.

```
select count(*) from my_table where col1 = "Sylvester" and col2 = "stallone"
```

Comment: OK, I will try it and let you now.

Comment: Actually this will not work for me. Are telling me how to make a database? I don't need that cause I already have database imported in assets and prepopulated.

Comment: I wasn't telling you how to make a db, I made that fiddle so its easy for people to help you because they hve a  table and some data to work with... It seems like i haven't understood your question but why wouldn't it work for you?

Comment: Cause I already have database created and populated, there's no need to do it again. The only thing I need is a way to compare the content of pressed buttons, to check if their columns in db match.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is what i've done so far.

```
 class MyStruct {
       public MyStruct (String lab, String t){
        label = lab;
        tag = t;
    }
       private String label;
       private String tag;
       }



@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);   //full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.spojnice);

        a1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA1);
        a2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA2);
        a3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA3);
        a4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA4);
        a5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA5);
        a6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA6);
        a7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA7);
        a8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA8);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB2);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB3);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB4);
        b5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB5);
        b6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB6);
        b7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB7);
        b8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB8);
        pitanje = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPitanje);

        nextQuestion();

        }

    public void nextQuestion() {

        TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();

        try{

            mDbHelper.open();

            Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestData(generateWhereClause());

            mAnsweredQuestions.add(c.getLong(0));

            ArrayList<MyStruct> labelsA = new ArrayList<MyStruct>();
            ArrayList<MyStruct> labelsB = new ArrayList<MyStruct>();

            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(2), "1")); // this tag should be the same to button that matches
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(3), "1"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(4), "2"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(5), "2"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(6), "3"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(7), "3"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(8), "4"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(9), "4"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(10), "5"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(11), "5"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(12), "6"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(13), "6"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(14), "7"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(15), "7"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(16), "8"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(17), "8"));

            Collections.shuffle(labelsA);
            Collections.shuffle(labelsB);

            pitanje.setText(c.getString(1));

            a1.setText(labelsA.get(0).label);
            a1.setTag(labelsA.get(0).tag);
            a1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b1.setText(labelsB.get(0).label);
            b1.setTag(labelsB.get(0).tag);
            b1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a2.setText(labelsA.get(1).label);
            a2.setTag(labelsA.get(1).tag);
            a2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b2.setText(labelsB.get(1).label);
            b2.setTag(labelsB.get(1).tag);
            b2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a3.setText(labelsA.get(2).label);
            a3.setTag(labelsA.get(2).tag);
            a3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b3.setText(labelsB.get(2).label);
            b3.setTag(labelsB.get(2).tag);
            b3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a4.setText(labelsA.get(3).label);
            a4.setTag(labelsA.get(3).tag);
            a4.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b4.setText(labelsB.get(3).label);
            b4.setTag(labelsB.get(3).tag);
            b4.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a5.setText(labelsA.get(4).label);
            a5.setTag(labelsA.get(4).tag);
            a5.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b5.setText(labelsB.get(4).label);
            b5.setTag(labelsB.get(4).tag);
            b5.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a6.setText(labelsA.get(5).label);
            a6.setTag(labelsA.get(5).tag);
            a6.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b6.setText(labelsB.get(5).label);
            b6.setTag(labelsB.get(5).tag);
            b6.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a7.setText(labelsA.get(6).label);
            a7.setTag(labelsA.get(6).tag);
            a7.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b7.setText(labelsB.get(6).label);
            b7.setTag(labelsB.get(6).tag);
            b7.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a8.setText(labelsA.get(7).label);
            a8.setTag(labelsA.get(7).tag);
            a8.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b8.setText(labelsB.get(7).label);
            b8.setTag(labelsB.get(7).tag);
            b8.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        }


        finally{  
            mDbHelper.close();
        }
    }
```

And in the top of my class I've made onClickListener, but I don't know how to continue. I don't know how to make that when I press one of the left buttons it waits untill I press the right button. And what if I press left button, then AGAIN left button? In that case I want do disregard previously press left button and continue from the last pressed left button.

```
final OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            MyStruct ms = (MyStruct) v.getTag();


            }
     };
```